# #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007f94e96b0b90> error when uploading file using carrier wave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am trying to use carrier wave to upload files in my rails app, i am using cloud 9 environment and i get `<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007f94e96b0b90>` error when i upload the file.

I also noticed that it didn't create a folder in the public folder like I was supposed to, here is my console result when I created the post.

```sql
INSERT INTO "reports" ("name", "attachment", "created_at", "updated_at")
  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [
    ["name", "file 1"],
    ["attachment", "#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007f94e96b0b90>"],
    ["created_at", "2019-05-29 09:32:03.690997"],
    ["updated_at", "2019-05-29 09:32:03.690997"]
  ]
```

I don't know why is is storing the file like this, any help will be appericiated.

Comment: `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` is not an error. The thing is, you're not saving a reference to the file on the database, you're saving the Ruby object instance of file itself. You might have just assign `Report#attachment` to a reference to the file on the server, or something like that.

Comment: I am new to Rails how can i fix it